# How to see filesystem (node) functions

Tags: node.js, fs

Is it possible to see node.js `fs` module source code?

In particular i wanted to check `mkdir` function and the `recursive` option.

I tried to check: https://github.com/nodejs/node , `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib` and `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules` without finding it.

Thanks for attention!

**EDIT:**

In the code i can see that there is an internal call to `binding.mkdir(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path), parseMode(mode, 'mode', 0o777), recursive, req);`, but i can't see a definition with four parameters. Where can i found that function?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can get your answer as to how fs recursive works. 
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2f45ad8060e13d5ac912335096d21526f2f9602b/lib/fs.js#L737

Comment: In the code i can see that there is an internal call to `binding.mkdir(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path),
                parseMode(mode, 'mode', 0o777), recursive, req);`, but i can't see a definition with four parameters. Where can i found that function?